# Excel macro for chart based on selection with custom name

Tags: vba, excel

I already found macro to create chart based on selection

```
Sub Charter()
    Dim my_range    As Range

    Set my_range = Selection
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=my_range
    Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

but cant figure out how to give it custom name (not generic `Chart <number>`) so that I can build another macros around it. I found couple of ways to create chart with name but I cant figure out how to connect those two macros. 
Any ideas what to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the Name property of the ActiveChart. You have to go for its parent object:

```
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "Bananas"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to use `ActiveSheet`, `Selection`, `Select` and `ActiveChart`, instead use fully qualified objects, like in the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Charter()

    Dim MyCht       As Object
    Dim my_range    As Range
    Dim ws          As Worksheet

    ' avoid using ActiveSheet, instead use fully qualifed objects
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <-- change "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    Set my_range = Selection

    ' set the Chart
    Set MyCht = ws.Shapes.AddChart2
    With MyCht ' modify the chart's properties
        .Chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=my_range
        .Name = "My Chart"
    End With

End Sub
```